# How to mount LUKS encrypted drive of old system with same VGname

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption, lvm, luks

I have two drives, an older and a newer one, both of which contain systems set up using Mint/Ubuntu with full disk encryption.  I want to mount the older one on the newer one to copy some of my old stuff across.

The Volume group names are the same on both systems.  I've found [Mount external hard drive with LUKS Encryption + LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646332/mount-external-hard-drive-with-luks-encryption-lvm) which tells me about vgimportclone.  It's not clear from the man page though whether this will change the volume group data on disk in a way that means I can't boot into the old system, which could be disastrous.

What's the safest way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The new system was relatively low value (some setup effort, but nothing hard to replace), so I decided to mess with that instead.

I booted from USB (using the mint install system), and did the following (where `sdb5 is the encrypted partition that houses the lvm data for my new system)

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb5 newdisk
vgimportclone /dev/mapper/newdisk
pvscan
vgscan
lvscan
```

I'm not sure that those scans are actually necessary, but i did them, and then I looked around with `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay`.  All looks fine.

I tried re-booting at this point, which didn't work.  Grub couldn't find the disk, and complained with a message like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225246/missing-root-vg-dropped-to-an-initramfs-shell-solved).

I booted back into the installer, and fixed up the references to `/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root` and `/dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap` in `/etc/grub/grub.cfg` and `/etc/fstab`.

The system boots, and I can now mount the old drive using the GUI tools (`nemo`), albeit it's a tad inelegant, with an error displayed from the attempt to mount the encrypted partition, after which the unecrypted one is available to mount.

So, it seems OK.  I've `grep`ed for `mint--vg` in /etc and /boot, and found nothing else to fix up.  I'll add more info here if I come across anything else that needs fixing up.