# Opening LUKS encrypted drive in nautilus results in "operation cancelled"

Tags: 16.04, mount, nautilus, encryption, luks

I'm on a Ubuntu 16.04 computer with a LUKS encrypted drive trying to mount an old Ubuntu 16.04 LUKS encrypted drive. When I open the drive in Nautilus, after entering the correct password I get the following pop-up error

> *Unable to access “127 GB Encrypted”*
>   Operation cancelled

Relevant? output of `sudo fdisk -l` after doing `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb3 my_encrypted_volume`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1D78C9DC-B51C-4729-8D7D-BB2B7C207511

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624   1550335    499712   244M Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  1550336 250068991 248518656 118.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume: 118.5 GiB, 127239454720 bytes, 248514560 sectors
```

I've tried a number of answers from [Mount encrypted volumes from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line) without success.

### If I do the accepted answer

([this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/279218/334823))

```
udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdb5
udisksctl mount -b /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root
```

I get something like `Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d3 is not a mountable filesystem.`

### If I do the highest voted answer

([this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/63598/334823))

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb3 my_encrypted_volume
sudo mkdir /media/my_device
sudo mount /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume /media/my_device
```

I get `mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'`

Comment: Have you tried to specify the  option --filesystem-type ?

Comment: @dajavex71 I did not. Care to elaborate?

Comment: You stated the following is received: I get something like Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d3 is not a mountable filesystem., My thought is that it needs to be told what type of filesystem, in order for the mount to be successful. Example: ext4, ext3, etc

Comment: Same error if I try `udisksctl mount --filesystem-type luks -b /dev/dm-4`

Comment: I think we need additional information.from the terminal prompt, what is the output of the following: `sudo fdisk --list'?

Comment: Try to unlock it with `cryptsetup luksOpen`

Comment: Updated in response to both your questions

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Scrolling through [one of the related questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686316/how-to-mount-luks-encrypted-drive-of-old-system-with-same-vgname?rq=1) I found an answer that worked.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb3 my_encrypted_volume
sudo vgimportclone /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume
```

This latter output a bunch of scary `WARNING` until

```
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" successfully renamed to "ubuntu-vg1"
Notifying lvmetad about changes since it was disabled temporarily.
(This resolves any WARNING message about restarting lvmetad that appears above.)
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg1" using metadata type lvm2
```

I then ran `sudo vgchange -ay` (possibly unnecessarily) and then ran

```
sudo mount /dev/ubuntu-vg1/root /media/my_device/
```

And voila! The drive appeared in Nautilus

Comment: Worked for me. Also, the `vgchange -ay` was necessary.

Comment: Worked for me on Mint 19, but now I'm trying to undo it, so I can remove the drive and insert another. `sudo umount /media/my_device` works, but then `sudo vgchange -a n mint-vg` complains that 'Logical volume mint-vg/root contains a filesystem in use. Can't deactivate volume group "mint-vg" with 2 open logical volume(s)'. So how do I deactivate it? Using `lvchange` somehow, maybe? And then, I assume, it's `sudo vgremove -f /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume` and `sudo cryptsetup luksClose my_encrypted_volume`?

Comment: Running this:
`sudo vgimportclone /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume`
 Resulted in this:
  `Device /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume has active LVs, deactivate first.`
To solve it, I've run `sudo gparted`, right click on the encrypted partition and "Deactivate". Hope it will help somebody in my same situation (I guess there's a command line for it too)

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command since the drive maybe deactivated due to many wrong password attempts or something else.

```
sudo vgchange -ay
```

You should get an output similar to below:

```
root@nc:~# vgchange -ay
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "pny-vg" now active
  3 logical volume(s) in volume group "nc-vg" now active
```